# Dependent ant task is executing before finishing the dependency task execution

Tags: java, ant, eclipse-plugin

I have written an ant script to build a plugin and publish feature as follows:

```
<project default="temp" name="build">

<target name="feature_export" depends="build-exility-Client">
     <echo>inside feature_export</echo>
    <pde.exportFeatures destination="C:\Users\akhilesh.kj\Desktop\Plugin" exportSource="false" exportType="directory" features="com.exility.exilant.feature" useJARFormat="true" /> 
</target>

    <target name="temp" depends="feature_export">
      <p2.publish.featuresAndBundles
            metadataRepository="file:/d:/a"
            artifactRepository="file:/d:/a"
            publishArtifacts="true"
            compress="true"
           source="C:\Users\akhilesh.kj\Desktop\Plugin"/>
   </target>    
</project>
```

Here, first 'feature_export' is getting executed.But before completing the execution(exporting the plugin and feature) Task 'temp' get started.Since task 'temp' is using plugin and feature jar that is output of 'feature_export' task,So it is not giving result as expected.

All I want is that firstly, complete 'feature_export' task with proper output then start 'temp' task.

I tried with sleep and waitfor command but that does not work for me.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known limitation

[Eclipse Bugtracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=58413)

It seems that they won't fix it.